# First fundamental of calculus

Tags: derivatives

Find $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-x^2}^{0} sin(8t^2)dt$$

Is this correct?
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-x^2}^{0} sin(8t^2)dt = -2x(-sin(8x^4))$$

Comment: No. ${d\over dt}\int_u^v f(x) = v’f(v)-u’f(u)$

Comment: Will the answer be $$2x sin(-8x^4)$$?

Comment: $8(-x^2)^2=8x^4 \neq -8x^4$

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the help

Comment:  glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more general than the "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus" is "Leigniz's rule", $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} f(x,t)dt= \frac{d\beta(x)}{dx}f(x,x)- \frac{d\alpha(x)}{dx}f(x,x)+ \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} dt$.

In $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-x^2}^0 sin(8t^2)dt$, we have $\alpha(x)= -x^2$, so $\frac{d\alpha}{dx}= -2x$, $\beta(x)= 0$ so $\frac{d\beta}{dx}= 0$, and $f(x,t)= sin(8t^2)$. f(x,t) is actually a function t only so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= 0$.

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-x^2}^0 sin(8t^2)dt= 0(sin(8x^2))- (-2x)sin(8x^2)+ 0= 2x sin(8x^2)$